# To get the input of the subquery in the output of the main Result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that contains the `subquery`

```
select doc_id from request 
where id in 
  (select r.root_id from request r, action a where  a.request_id = r.id and a.ID 
   in (1253960076) );
```

I want to output the a.id in the main result set means I want doc_id as well as a.id in the main result. I am trying to use alias but that is not working. Is there any way we can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INNER JOIN between request and action table.

```
SELECT r.doc_id,a.id
FROM request r
INNER JOIN action a
ON r.id=a.request_id
WHERE a.id in (1253960076)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
r.doc_id,
a.ID
FROM 
request r
INNER JOIN action a ON a.request_id = r.id
WHERE
a.ID IN (1253960076)
```